# Two .net core API and identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two Web API one for each of my two applications. Need my users to be able to log into either. Do I need to add asp.identity to both API projects.i will use a third party identity provider to authenticate the users.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using identity provider like Identity Server ,you can store users in database and use Asp.Net Identity in identity provider's application to manage users .

When you want to authenticate user in your client application , it will redirect user to identity provider application's login page to let user enter their credential , then the identity provider application will validate user's credential in database and issue ID token and access token if you want to access a protected resource .

You doesn't need to add asp.net identity to your client(web app/api) applications unless you want to map/save the users to your local user database . Adding Asp.Net Identity to identity provider application to help manage user is always a good choice .